# Backbone: Setting server response from one model to another

Tags: backbone.js

After login user gets redirected to another page. So the response Login model gets from server, it tries to set to another model.
Second model gets set properly from the first model.But when it reaches another page's view, it becomes empty.
**Models**

```
var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://localhost:3000/login',

    defaults: {
        email:"",
        password:""
    },
    parse: function(resp) {
        console.log('Model: Got the response back');
        return resp;
    },
    login: function() {
        console.log('Model: Login function:'+JSON.stringify(this));
        this.save(
            {}, {
                success: function(resp) {
                    console.log('success'+JSON.stringify(resp));
                    dashboardModel.set(resp.result);
                    window.location = 'templates/dashboard.html'
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log('error: '+JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
    },
    redirect: function() {
        console.log('inside redirect method');
    }
});
var loginModel = new LoginModel();

var DashboardModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        campaignName:"",
        orderedAndGoal:"",
        status:"",
        endDate:"",
    },
    parse: function(resp) {
        console.log('Model: Got the response back');
        return resp;
    }
});
var dashboardModel = new DashboardModel();
```

**View**

```
var DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template:_.template('<div>'+
                        '<h3><%= campaignName %></h3>'+
                        '<span><%= orderedAndGoal %>, </span>'+
                        '<span><%= status %>, </span>'+
                        '<span><%= endDate %>, </span>'+
                        '</div>'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); 
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('what happens here')
        var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));
    },
});
var dashboardView = new DashboardView({model: dashboardModel});
dashboardView.render();
$(".container").append(dashboardView.el);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are literally navigating to another HTML page with `window.location = ...`.  That's not gonna work.  When the browser navigates to another page, all your running code and any variables they set are blown away.  Backbone is all about creating "single page applications (SPA)" where there is only 1 page loaded by the browser and then the DOM is dynamically changed at runtime.  Take a look at `Backbone.Router` as a starting point for understanding this.  You'll call methods on this router to move the user to another "view" rather than touching `window.location`

Fix that and your code should work :)